# What is the difference between CacheResolver and KeyGenerator and when to use each one of them

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am adding a caching mechanism to my web application.
After doing a research I decided to use `Ehcache` with Spring.

Adding `@Cachable` annotation to a method will execute the method once and for any further invocations the response will be returned from the cache.

The problem is that I need to decide at runtime (let's suppose according to the logged in user) which cache I want to use.

I have come to a point where I need to decide whether to use `KeyGenerators` or `cacheResolver`.

I searched for best practices, when to use each one of them but did not find any good readings. I hope If anybody can clarify the differences and elaborate on best practices and to do's and not to do's.

KeyGenerator:

```
  @Bean
  public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
    return new KeyGenerator() {
      @Override
      public Object generate(Object o, Method method, String loggedInUserId) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("cache_");
        sb.append(loggedInUserId);
        return sb;
      }
    };
```

CacheResolver

```
class loggedInUserCacheResolver implements CacheResolver {
@Override
    public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
        Collection<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<>();
        // do some logic and return caches to use.
        return caches;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `KeyGenerator` will only allow you to manipulate the creation of the cache key. However *all* keys will still belong to a single cache, even though they will not have any collision.

The `CacheResolver` allow you to use logic to pick which `Cache` to use.

Given your initial statement, you would need a `CacheResolver` for your use case. Note that I did not double check if the cache is resolved *once* or for *each* invocation.

Note that you could combine both annotations to have a custom cache and a custom key definition.

Comment: has been wondering about 2 months inside SO to find this explanation